# Visible password in printers.conf

Tags: printing

Is possible to hide a password in printers.conf? I know its accessible only by root, but ...plaintext...
Or is possible to setup authentication page evertime when i print a page? Thanks

```
# Printer configuration file for CUPS v1.5.3
# Written by cupsd
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE WHEN CUPSD IS RUNNING
<Printer central-test>
UUID urn:uuid:b80cce5d-7ca5-3c70-7bf8-a78c73b7e048
AuthInfoRequired username,password
Info central-test
MakeModel Generic 55BW-5eSeriesPS(P)
DeviceURI smb://domain\user:password@address/printer
State Idle
StateTime 1414766521
Type 8401100
Accepting Yes
Shared No
JobSheets none none
QuotaPeriod 0
PageLimit 0
KLimit 0
OpPolicy default
ErrorPolicy stop-printer
</Printer>
```